# How to edit Chrome omnibar auto-complete entries?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, autocomplete, address-bar

In Google Chrome omnibar, whenever I type `wwwjdic`, an entry "wwwjdic.com" will be shown (because I have visited the website http://wwwjdic.com before).

Now the problem is that if I type `WWWJDIC` + <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, Chrome takes me to the website http://wwwjdic.com, but this behavior is not what I wanted.

Is there a way to "customize" or edit entries shown in the omnibar?

Comment: How do you want it edited?

Comment: @soandos like Ctrl-H -> Edit Items

Comment: See [these other](http://superuser.com/questions/328515/chrome-remove-url-from-autocomplete-which-doesnt-show-up-in-history/) [questions](http://superuser.com/questions/326531/removing-past-searches-from-google-chromes-omnibar/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://news.softpedia.com/news/How-to-Remove-Annoying-Omnibox-Suggestions-in-Google-Chrome-268740.shtml

Scroll down to the wwwjd.com and push SHIFT + DELETE and it should never pop up again (unless you go to that site or type it in again which then you can just shift + delete it again

Comment: please explain what the link is

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just write a space after WWWJDIC? No website has a space on its URL, so that would kind of solve the problem... Though i understand if you are not completely satisfied wit this solution, since what you asked for was a way to change the omnibar's auto-completion behaviour, not the best way to use its current behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You could uncheck "Use a prediction service to help complete searches and URLs typed in the address bar" (under Options | Under the hood) to stop it from doing that.

Comment: but of course that would simply disable that service. what i wanted to do is to remove certain terms from that cached list. Something like Ctrl-H -> Edit Items

Comment: What’s wrong with `Ctrl+H->Edit Items`? The suggestions in the Omnibar are drawn from your history. If you don’t want something from your past coming back, erase it. `;-p`

Comment: @Synetech you are missing the point, the omnibar has items that are not in the history as well, in fact, the history and the omnibar is not so related ! (btw look at my edited question)

Comment: Nope, sorry. It does in fact use the history, just not in the way that you are thinking. Look in your User Data folder and you will see numerous history files, one for each month, plus one called simply `History`, and another called `Archived History`. Not all of the data is available via the History page, yet Chrome keeps and uses it nonetheless. What you want is a way to edit the stuff that is not shown in the History page without having to resort to manually editing the SQLite3 databases.