# Disable history search from Chrome Omnibar

Tags: google-chrome, browser, address-bar

I'm using Google Chrome and I'm wondering if there's a way to disable items from my history appearing in the dropdown when I search or type a URL?

I'd like to keep saving my history in the browser, but just disable the searching from the omnibox.

Comment: Related? [Removing past searches from Google Chrome's omnibar](http://superuser.com/questions/326531/removing-past-searches-from-google-chromes-omnibar)

Answer (score 0):

Try running Chrome with the [disable history suggestions flag](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#disable-history-quick-provider), `--disable-history-quick-provider`.

Comment: Do you know the way to do this on a Mac?

Comment: @Volomike http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags