# Disable URL suggestion in Chrome temporarily

Tags: google-chrome

Is it possible to disable chrome's auto URL suggestion temporarily which I can use during presentations meetings where I dont want to show my previous history when I start typing office website in the address bar?

Comment: For such tasks I usually just use another browser or plainly another user account (desktop clutter can be shameful sometimes ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Guest profile](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6130773?hl=en) feature available in Google Chrome.

> When friends and family members browse as guests on your computer, none of their browsing history or cookies are saved. They also can’t see or change your Chrome information or settings.

This should enable you to use Google Chrome during presentations or meetings while keeping your browsing history private.

### To browse as guest:

1. Click on **Person** icon at top right of Google Chrome
2. Click on **Switch Person**

   [image]
3. In the lower left corner of the dialog, click **Browse as Guest.**

   [image]

Comment: I had no clue about this Guest Profile feature. Good answer.

Answer (score 0):

One possible idea is that you install Chrome again and don't Sign In.

Since you begin fresh, there won't be anything to distract.

Comment: I need to switch it off temporarily while in meetings and other times I need to use it normally.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible. If you use your computer for both business and personal use, you really should have different user accounts. Or simply use two different browsers, one browser for personal, another for business. If you're familiar with SQLite, you can check this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/330125) which explains using SQLite browser to manually delete auto-complete suggestions.